# Bounded buffer problem - Why producer can only fill up n–1 buffer?

Tags: synchronization, producer-consumer

I read a lecture about synchronization.

In this lecture there were 2 slides about the bounded buffer problem (see below).

My question is about the sentence marked in yellow, why it's true that producer can only fill up to n-1 buffer cells? thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the first slide the shared data includes definition of two variables, *in* and *out* . Both variables have limited values in the range of 0 through n - 1, which matches the index values specified for the array named *buffer*.

Assume the variable *in* is initialized to 0. The condition for the *while* loop in the producer is *in+1 mod n = out*. While this condition prevents overwriting unread data it also manages to use only n-1 of the array elements.

The condition of the producer's while loop is an example of trying to be just a little too clever. The producer needs to know when the array is full. A less clever approach is to have one more variable storing the number of elements in the buffer. Let's call it *count*, which is initialized to 0. Upon adding an element to the buffer the producer increments *count*. Upon reading an element from the buffer the consumer decrements *count*. The buffer is full when count = n. The buffer is empty when count = 0. This approach also works and has the advantage of using all n elements of the array.